# Fastest way to retrieve an object from array of objects with large data sets(50k records)

Tags: arrays, object, search, find, underscore.js

here totalObjects contains around 40k records from which i am finiding an object which is present in sapObjs(20k records). So when ever i found the object i am trying to change its property values. For this operation it is taking more than 200secs.Can any one suggest me the way to overcome this and improve the performance. I have already tried the alternate ways for _.find such as filter and other array functions but i got that underscore js giving the results faster than those.But underscore is said to be slower, I am to get the other ways to do this ,so can any one help me out of this issue.

```
        for (i = 0,sapLength = sapObjs.length;i < sapLength; i++) {
            debugger;


            currRecord = entriesInserted[sapObjs[i].name];
            if (currRecord) {

                dummyObj = _.find(totalObjects,{name:sapObjs[i].name});

                dummyObj["sap_desc"] = sapObjs[i].sap_desc;
                dummyObj.source = "";

            }
            else {
                entriesInserted[sapObjs[i].name] = sapOpbs[i];

                totalObjects.push(sapObjs[i]);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a look up hash.  Here's a rough page I hacked together to illustrate.  Using the _.find, the test took 400+ seconds.  Using a lookup hash, it took about 40ms.  Almost instant.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // using globals so this can be run in separate steps.
        var source_sapObjs = [];
        var source_totalObjects = [];

        function createArrays(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt',
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'GET'
            }).done(function(textFile){

                var words = textFile.split('\n');

                // create an array with 20k and 40k records.
                for(var i = 0; i < 20000; i++){
                    source_sapObjs.push({name: words[i], sap_desc: 'DESC-' + words[i]});
                }
                for(var j = 0; j < 40000; j++){
                    source_totalObjects.push({name: words[j], sap_desc: 'none'});
                }

                console.log("source_sapObjs.length:", source_sapObjs.length);
                console.log("source_totalObjects.length:", source_totalObjects.length);
                console.log("finished creating arrays");
            });
        }

        function iter_arrays(){
            var dummyObj = null;
            var sapObjs = source_sapObjs.slice(); // create a copy so I can re-run this multiple times.
            var totalObjects = source_totalObjects.slice(); // create a copy so I can re-run this multiple times.


            var start = new Date().getTime();

            var totalObjectsHash = {};
            for(var k = 0; k < totalObjects.length; k++){
                totalObjectsHash[totalObjects[k].name] = totalObjects[k];
            }

            for (var i = 0, sapLength = sapObjs.length; i < sapLength; i++) {
                    //dummyObj = _.find(totalObjects,{name:sapObjs[i].name});
                    dummyObj = totalObjectsHash[sapObjs[i].name];
                    dummyObj["sap_desc"] = sapObjs[i].sap_desc;
                    dummyObj.source = "";
            }

            var end = new Date().getTime();
            var time = end - start;
            console.log('Execution time: ' + time);
            console.log(_.map(totalObjects, 'sap_desc'));

        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

To run it, create the page locally on your computer, open it in chrome, open the developer tools, and from the console run the first function.  When that finishes, run the second function.